# Connect ESP8266 with Android Studio App

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-uno-wifi

Hey guys I have ESP8266 and want to remote control a sailboat with it. Till now it works fine but how is it possible to send continuous data between the Arduino/ESP8266 and my smartphone? If you need any further information just add a comment.
Thanks guys

Comment: Do you have an ESP8266 dev board like a NodeMCU or an Arduino plus an ESP8266 with AT firmware on it? The design of the project is up to you, but normally you would let the ESP create a wifi access point, connect with the smartphone and then send messages over the network via websockets or similar (also depending on the question above)

Comment: @chrisl, why 'web'? plain TCP socket or UDP will be faster

Comment: @chrisl I use Arduino Uno + ESP8266